# Internal Browser for debug for local Azure ASP.NET MVC2 under Visual Studio 2010 RC ????

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, visual-studio-2010

Wanting to have IE open in a tab in Visual Studio, rather than as a separate IE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if something like this existed. Having an external browser (IE or Firefox) pop up has been the de facto standard for ASP.NET debugging for ages.

But why would you desperately need this feature anyway? You can simply leave the browser open and reload the resource when something has changed. There is no need to close the browser when you stop your debug session.